# Python 3.7 in Conda env on M1

Tags: conda, pyenv, mini-forge

Trying to use `Python3.7` in a new environment in Conda.  I installed the `x86_64` version of `brew` into the default location (`/usr/bin`) alongside the `arm64` version (`3.7` isn't available on `arm64`).  I was able to install `Python3.7` via the `x86_64` `brew`, and it shows up in VSCode as a Python interpreter.

This is the `environment.yml`:

```
name: aiclass
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - tk
  - numpy
  - pillow
  - pytorch
```

but I get `ResolvePackageNotFound: - python=3.7`

I also set `pyenv global 3.7.16` and that works.

Can I specify other Python installations to Conda?  Or install from a different channel other than `conda-forge`?